# Getting an error (code = SCRIPT5009) while trying to initialise a Google Maps map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to develop a web mobile app that allows people to navigate between different POI's however I've come across an error when trying to implement the Google Maps Api.

Here's the code for those interested:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mobile_Map_Application</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body{ height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map{height:100%;}
</style>
<script>
var map;
function initialise(){
map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map' ), {
zoom: 17,
center: { lat: 51.887082, lng:  -2.088722 }
} );
initialise();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=initialise" async defer>
</script>
</head>
```

I'm getting the following error :

> SCRIPT5009: 'google' is undefined

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

Your `initialise()` function doesn't know the `google` object yet, because the `google` object is only known AFTER the Google API script is loaded.

---

### The solution

The easiest way to fix this, is to do this :

1. Put the code of your `initialise()` function AFTER the Google API script's `script` tag
2. Remove the `async defer` from the Google API script's `script` tag

**Additionally :**

1. You're also missing an `}` at the end of your `initialise()` function.
2. You'll need an HTML element with an id `map` for your code to work.

---

### Working code

Check out [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fuLmfeg5/) for how to fix your code!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `initialise();` once in your code, but this could execute before the Google Maps JS has loaded.

You also specify `initialise` as the callback function, in

```
<script 
    type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=initialise" async defer>
```

This will execute the `initialise` function once the Maps JS has loaded.  That's all you need; delete the `initialise();` line you have in your own JS.

PS: John's answer points out a couple of things you need to do.

- You need a closing `}` at the end of the function,
- And you need `<div id="map"></div>` in your page.

PPS: you don't need to specify the `sensor=false` argument any more when loading the Maps API.